# Problems with netdom trust

Tags: active-directory, trust-relationship

First, I want to create a one way forest trust with this command on the "main.adds" domain :

```
netdom trust main.adds /Domain:second.adds /Add /UserD:SECOND\administrator /PasswordD:* /UserO:MAIN\administrator /PasswordO:*
```

It returns (french Windows version, but I think it is easily understandable) :

```
Paramètre incorrect.
Essayez « NETDOM HELP » pour plus d’informations.
```

Since I cannot find any error with my syntax, and want to make some more tests before resolving this, I created the forest trust with the GUI in domain and trusts console with no problem (name resolution is fine between the 2 forests with conditional redirectors).

Since the trust was finally created with the GUI, I didn't run netdom with the "/ForestTRANsitive:Yes" parameter.

Then, I have tried to enable SID History, still on "main.adds" domain :

```
netdom trust main.adds /Domain:second.adds /EnableSIDHistory:Yes
```

This time, the command marks operation as successful but displays SID History as disabled.

same problem for `/EnablePIMTrust:Yes`

Both forests are running Windows Server 2022 in 2016 forest mode. Both forests are one domain only and with no more configuration after their creation (only default AD and GPO - "main" domain as only one more OU with one user account inside). Only changes are for both DNS, where inverse zone and conditional redirector were created.

Any ideas for both problems (trust add with netdom and EnableSIDHistory / EnablePIMTrust keeping disabled) ?

My main concern is the second one.

EDIT: No one with any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: Netdom typically uses the single-label (NetBIOS) domain name. Have you tried that?

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion, unfortunally, I have tried this already